# Cursor is not giving the count of column in Android

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I m trying to get the path of all song present in sd card in string array but it is not storing in the array else it is overriding on it, 
Please help me, code ....

```
String[] projection = new String[] {MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};
    Cursor mCur = managedQuery(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,projection, null, null, null);
    mCur.moveToFirst();
    path=new String[mCur.getColumnCount()]; 
    while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false) {       
    for (i=0; i<mCur.getColumnCount(); i++) 
    {path[i]=mCur.getString(i);
            System.out.println(",,,,,,,,"+mCur.getColumnCount());
            System.out.println(path[i]+i);}
            mCur.moveToNext(); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, should do what you want

```
String[] projection = new String[] {MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};
Cursor mCur = managedQuery(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,projection, null, null, null);
// check if there is data returned or not
if (mCur.moveToFirst()) {
    // you should use getCount() rather than getColumnCount()
    // getCount() is the number of rows, while getColumnCount() is the number of columns returned
    // remember your projection?? only return 1 column.
    path = new String[mCur.getCount()]; 
    int whichColumn = mCur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
    int i = 0;
    do {
        path[i] = mCur.getString(whichColumn);
        i++;
    } while (mCur.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: your answer worked for me I was also stuck in the same problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

why are you using For loop, use do whole loop as

```
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
                       // get the data from here

          }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Or use while loop as

```
                   if (mCursor != null) {
                   mCursor.moveToFirst();
                   while(!mCursor.isAfterLast()){

                        // get the data from here

                       mCursor.moveToNext();
                    }
               }
```